# using regex to substitute the half space in two Persian strings in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

The data I am working on is as follows:
(AJ_SIM فتنه برانگیز) ) ) ) ) (MV (ADJ (AJ_SIM روشن) ) (V (V_PRES_POS_3 می گردد) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) 
There are some Persian words which were separated by space and when I split the contents of each file, they are considered as separate strings. I have to find each two Persian strings which are after the previous one like "  برانگیز"، "فنته" and replace that space with a half-space. But they must be in the same list with their tags. I mean the only change I have to do is to find these kinds of strings and join them with half space and save them with the previous strings in a list with the same order. 
Here is my code:

```
import os
import codecs
import re



###opening the files from a folder in a directory
matches=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Test2"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pts"):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, file))
print(matches)
print(len(matches))

###reading files 
for i, f in enumerate(matches):
    with codecs.open(f, "r", "utf-8") as fp:
        text=fp.read().split()
        #print(text)
        #print (len(text))
        print(type(text))

 ###substituting space with half-space       
        original_pattern= r'\b(\w)\s(\w)'
        new_pattern= '\\1\u200c\\2'
        list_words=[]
        for a in text:
            words= re.sub(original_pattern, new_pattern, a)
            list_words.append(words)
            #print(type(a))
            print(list_words)
```

Here is a sample of splitted text of each file:
['(ROOT', '(S', '(VP', '(VPS', '(NP', '(NP', '(N_EZ', '(N_PL_COM_EZ_LOC', 'کشورهای)', ')', '(ADJ', '(AJ_SIM', 'درحال', 'توسعه)', ')', ')', '(Punc', '(PUNC', '،)', ')', ')', '(VP', '(NP', '(N_YA', '(N_YA_SING_COM', 'زمانی)', ')', '(nid', '1)', ')', '(VP', '(PP', '(PREP', '(P', 'به)', ')', '(N', '(N_SING_COM', 'استقلال)', ')', ')', '(MV', '(N', '(N_SING_COM', 'دست)', ')', '(V', '(V_SIM_POS_PA_6', 'یافتند)', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', '(CL_1', '(Conj', '(CONJ', 'که)', ')', '(VPSD', '(VP', '(ADV', '(ADV_SIM_GENR', 'مآلاً)', ')', '(VP', '(PP', '(PP', '(PREP', '(P', 'از)', ')', '(NP', '(N_EZ', '(N_SING_COM_EZ', 'سنت)', ')', '(NP', '(NP_C', '(N', '(N_PL_COM', 'علوم)', ')', '(N_C', '(Conj', '(CONJ', 'و)', ')', '(N_YA', '(N_YA_SING_COM', 'تکنولوژی', 'ای)', ')', ')', ')', '(CL', '(Conj', '(CONJ', 'که)', ')', '(VPSD', '(VP', '(AUX', '(V_NIN_POS_AUX', 'بتوان)', ')', '(VP', '(NP', '(PRON', '(PRO_DEMO_SING', 'آن)', ')', '(PostP', '(POSTP', 'را)', ')', ')', '(VP', '(ADJ', '(AJ_SIM', 'مدرن)', ')', '(MV', '(N', '(N_SING_COM', 'تلقی)', ')', '(V', '(V_SIM_POS_PA_3', 'نمود)', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', '(Punc', '(PUNC', '،)', ')', ')', '(VP', '(ADJ', '(AJ_SIM', 'برخوردار)', ')', '(V', '(V_COP_NEG_PA_6', 'نبودند)', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', '(Punc', '(PUNC', '.)', ')', ')', ')']

The only change I expect is that the strings which are like 'درحال', 'توسعه)' after each other to be joined together with a half space.

Comment: Because we don't have the files we can't produce the results to see what is going on. Can you at least show the output of this?

Comment: @ROAR check it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced in re so I'm not sure how sub works but here's something that will put your Persian words together (with my limited re knowledge):

```
import re

pervious_is_persian= False
# Add all your persian letters here
all_persian_letters_r = r'[آابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهیئؤأإة]'
text = ['(ROOT', '(S', '(VP', '(VPS', '(NP', '(NP', '(N_EZ', '(N_PL_COM_EZ_LOC', 'کشورهای)', ')', '(ADJ', '(AJ_SIM', 'درحال', 'توسعه)', ')', ')', '(Punc', '(PUNC', '،)', ')', ')', '(VP', '(NP', '(N_YA', '(N_YA_SING_COM', 'زمانی)', ')', '(nid', '1)', ')', '(VP', '(PP', '(PREP', '(P', 'به)', ')', '(N', '(N_SING_COM', 'استقلال)', ')', ')', '(MV', '(N', '(N_SING_COM', 'دست)', ')', '(V', '(V_SIM_POS_PA_6', 'یافتند)', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', '(CL_1', '(Conj', '(CONJ', 'که)', ')', '(VPSD', '(VP', '(ADV', '(ADV_SIM_GENR', 'مآلاً)', ')', '(VP', '(PP', '(PP', '(PREP', '(P', 'از)', ')', '(NP', '(N_EZ', '(N_SING_COM_EZ', 'سنت)', ')', '(NP', '(NP_C', '(N', '(N_PL_COM', 'علوم)', ')', '(N_C', '(Conj', '(CONJ', 'و)', ')', '(N_YA', '(N_YA_SING_COM', 'تکنولوژی', 'ای)', ')', ')', ')', '(CL', '(Conj', '(CONJ', 'که)', ')', '(VPSD', '(VP', '(AUX', '(V_NIN_POS_AUX', 'بتوان)', ')', '(VP', '(NP', '(PRON', '(PRO_DEMO_SING', 'آن)', ')', '(PostP', '(POSTP', 'را)', ')', ')', '(VP', '(ADJ', '(AJ_SIM', 'مدرن)', ')', '(MV', '(N', '(N_SING_COM', 'تلقی)', ')', '(V', '(V_SIM_POS_PA_3', 'نمود)', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', '(Punc', '(PUNC', '،)', ')', ')', '(VP', '(ADJ', '(AJ_SIM', 'برخوردار)', ')', '(V', '(V_COP_NEG_PA_6', 'نبودند)', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', '(Punc', '(PUNC', '.)', ')', ')', ')']
words = []
for i in range(len(text)):
    if pervious_is_persian:
        if re.search(all_persian_letters_r,text[i]) is not None: 
            # current is persian
            text[i]=text[i-1]+'\u200c'+text[i] #
        else:
            # current isn't persian 
            # so add text[i-1] and text[i] to list
            words.append(text[i-1])
            words.append(text[i])
            pervious_is_persian = False
    else: # previous isn't persian
        if re.search(all_persian_letters_r,text[i]) is not None:
            # current is persian
            pervious_is_persian = True
        else: # current isn't persian
            words.append(text[i])
print(words)
```

I'm sure you can improve and implement it in your program somehow.
**Edited the answer above:**
Is this what you needed?
If so, it's easier to not split the text in the first place:

```
import re
text = fp.read()
all_persian_letters_r = r'[آابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهیئؤأإة]'
to_change = re.findall(all_persian_letters_r+'+\s',text)
for i in to_change:
    text = text.replace(i,i[:-1]+'\u200c')
    # 'ح' was missing from those letters. That was why it had
    # some problems. you might wanna add vowels (and anything else you need 
    # finding) to this too.
    # before this edit I came up with a hacky way to circumvent that but 
    # adding more letters is always a better solution.
```

Comment: thanks but the Persian words are separated from their tags which are in the text. And the output I get is like the following:                                    ['علاوه\u200cبر)', 'چهار)', 'محور)', 'یادشده)', 'وحدت)', 'در)', 'شرایط)', 'کنونی)', 'جامعه)', 'می\u200cتوان)', 'شاخصه\u200cهای)', 'رفتاری)', 'و)', 'عینی)', 'دیگری)', 'را)', 'نیز)', 'جستجو)', 'کرد)', 'که)', 'جداکننده)', 'مرز)', 'خودی)', 'از)', 'بیگانه)', 'می\u200cباشد)']

Comment: What you gave me was the result of `text=fp.read().split()` correct? There's no space in those words so of course you can't replace them with half-space. I don't know what the text looked like before split (it's very confusing to try and figure out without knowing what to look for let alone piecing it back together). Please edit your question with at least one example of `fp.read()` if that has the whole words and tags together.

Comment: Edited the answer. Check if this was what you asked for.

Comment: Edited again because it was missing a 'ح' and my way of dealing with that was too cumbersome.